# Есть ли возможность указать относительный путь для declare module в Type Script?

Tags: javascript, typescript

У меня есть часть кода написанная на type script.

`./src/index.ts`

```
export const object = {
    init: init,
}
```

Мне надо, что бы реализация функции находилась в другом месте.

В интернете я посмотрел, что для этого в ts используется `declare`

Можно указать

```
declare module "modules/index.mjs"

import * as init from 'modules/index.mjs'

export const object = {
    init: init,
}
```

Так в import подставляется путь, но нельзя указать относительный, что требуется для импортов модуля.

Есть ли возможность указать относительный путь для `declare module` или отключить проверку в `tsconfig.json` ?

Comment: а чем обычный импорт не подошел?

Comment: так получается.

Comment: все еще непонятно, зачем использовать declare, если можно использовать обычный import?

Comment: У меня нет при сборке модулей которые исполняют код

Comment: тогда смотри лучше в сторону: [Global .d.ts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-d-ts.html)